# Continue playback of YouTube player while rotating device with separate orientation layouts

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am trying to add a View containing a YouTube Player to an Activity that keeps on playing when I rotate the device. Since the UI contains more than just the video, I am using a `YouTubePlayerFragment`.

When the orientation changes from portrait to landscape, the system should use a different layout file. This layout also includes the YouTube player as a view which does not take up the whole screen. Below you will find the bare minimum code to reproduce the problem (for a fresh Android app, minimum API level 19).

```
package com.example.youtubefragmenttest;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final String YOUTUBE_DEV_KEY = "[your youtube dev key here]";

    private static final String TAG_YOUTUBE_FRAGMENT = "YoutubePlayerFragment";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        YouTubePlayerFragment retainedYoutubeFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_YOUTUBE_FRAGMENT);
        if (retainedYoutubeFragment == null) {
            retainedYoutubeFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
            retainedYoutubeFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, retainedYoutubeFragment, TAG_YOUTUBE_FRAGMENT);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        retainedYoutubeFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_DEV_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

        if (!wasRestored) {
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo("um4TrbU2Eic");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }
}
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.youtubefragmenttest.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know the developers of the YouTubePlayer API recommend handling orientation changes manually. This is also the accepted answer in [How to retain instance of fragment of fragment playing video after change in orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871050/how-to-retain-instance-of-fragment-of-fragment-playing-video-after-change-in-ori). Unfortunately, this will not work for me because there are too many complex differences between the layouts of portrait view and landscape view.

The documentation hints at a way to fix this such that `boolean wasRestored` in the callback method `onInitializationSuccess` is `true`, but this is the actual problem: `wasRestored` in the code above is *always* `false`.

Bottom line: how do you keep the YouTube player continue playing on orientation change while keeping separate layouts per orientation (which is the main difference with linked question)?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a solution that uses YoutubePlayerFragment? I've done something similar using YoutubeBaseActivity, if you're interested. I use a linear layout that switches orientation from horizontal to vertical, depending on orientation. The video keeps playing as the orientation changes (and when switching to fullscreen as well). I think I took the basic idea from the sample code and then just ran with it. Maybe https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications can give you some ideas too if you haven't looked at it already.

Comment: I use a `YouTubePlayerFragment` because the player is a small part of the UI. Furthermore, a `YouTubeBaseActivity` removes the Action Bar from the UI alongside some other changes to the layout.

I already checked the sample apps you mentioned, but the few that have the visual functionality that I desire handle orientation change manually. So unfortunately that is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

`onInitializationSuccess` returns a `YoutubePlayer` object that has a function on `getCurrentTimeMillis()`. Save this object as an activity instance (`this.player = youTubePlayer`) inside `onInitializationSuccess`. Before the activity is destroyed(`oPause/onStop`), get the current time and pass is to the retained fragment to be stored.

Comment: Technically this would work, but it is not an acceptable solution: since the video is reloaded instead of restored, it can cause YouTube ads to start playing again.

Comment: Ahhh, that could be a problem