# Why does my YouTube Player keep pausing when I tilt my device from portrait to landscape mode?

Tags: android, youtubeplayer

I am incorporating YoutubePlayerView in my app. It works perfectly fine in portrait mode but doesn't work in landscape mode. I am attaching the XML as well as java code for it. Please provide a valid solution for the same.

xml code :

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/pipyoutubevideoview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

java code :

```
youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youtubeUrl);
                youTubePlayer.play();
```

Comment: does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811557/continue-playback-of-youtube-player-while-rotating-device-with-separate-orientat

Comment: no, it does integrate well with my code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `manifest` :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Your welcome, If this helps you please check my answer.